# predict with glmer where new data is a Raster Stack of fixed efefcts

Tags: r, raster, glm, lme4

I have constructed models in `glmer` and would like to predict these on a `rasterStack` representing the fixed effects in my model. my `glmer` model is in the form of:

```
m1<-glmer(Severity ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + (1 | Year) + (1 | Ecoregion), family=binomial( logit ))
```

As you can see, I have random effects which I don't have as spatial layer - for example 'year'. Therefore the problem is really predicting `glmer` on `rasterStacks` when you don't have the random effects data random effects layers. If I use it out of the box without adding my random effects I get an error.

```
 m1.predict=predict(object=all.var, model=m1, type='response',  progress="text", format="GTiff") 
Error in predict.averaging(model, blockvals, ...) :
```

Comment: `predict.merMod` takes a data frame and returns a vector. Can you give a reproducible example?  I'm not terribly familiar with `rasterStack`s; perhaps someone else can tell you how to convert back and forth.

Comment: PS: any particular reason you're using `glmer` and not `lmer` (since you have no `family` argument, all recent versions of `glmer` should have given you a warning)

Comment: You can covert a RasterStack with `as.data.frame`, but this may not be a good approach with very large raster data sets. In that case it is better (but sometimes a bit more complicated) to use `raster::predict` (see my answer below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very brief, and does not indicated what, if any, trouble you have encountered. This seems to work 'out of the box', but perhaps not in your case. See `?raster::predict` for options.

```
library(raster)   
# example data. See ?raster::predict
logo <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
p <- matrix(c(48, 48, 48, 53, 50, 46, 54, 70, 84, 85, 74, 84, 95, 85, 
   66, 42, 26, 4, 19, 17, 7, 14, 26, 29, 39, 45, 51, 56, 46, 38, 31, 
   22, 34, 60, 70, 73, 63, 46, 43, 28), ncol=2)
a <- matrix(c(22, 33, 64, 85, 92, 94, 59, 27, 30, 64, 60, 33, 31, 9,
   99, 67, 15, 5, 4, 30, 8, 37, 42, 27, 19, 69, 60, 73, 3, 5, 21,
   37, 52, 70, 74, 9, 13, 4, 17, 47), ncol=2)
xy <- rbind(cbind(1, p), cbind(0, a))
v <- data.frame(cbind(pa=xy[,1], extract(logo, xy[,2:3])))
v$Year <- sample(2000:2001, nrow(v), replace=TRUE) 


library(lme4)
m <- lmer(pa ~ red + blue + (1 | Year), data=v)

# here adding Year as a constant, as it is not a variable (RasterLayer) in the RasterStack object
x <- predict(logo, m, const=(data.frame(Year=2000)))
```

Comment: I have updated my question. The issue is using predicting random effects model when you don't have the random effects layers

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have the random effects, just use `re.form=~0` in your `predict` call to predict at the population level:

```
x <- predict(logo, m, re.form=~0)
```

works without complaint for me with @RobertH's example (although I don't know if correctly)

Comment: Both answers have worked with my data, exactly what I was looking for. I guess then a question arises on whether not including random effects in the predictions affects the outcome map/predictions in a significant way. I know this is probably a different question..but would appreciate your thoughts...however brief

Comment: if one wants to use only one of the two random effects..for example in my case if in the predictions I want to use the 'ecoregion' random effect and not 'year' how would I configure the `re.form` argument?

Comment: I have tried this but  `re.form = ~ ecoregion` doesn't work while `re.form = (~1|ecoregion)` works. However, my random effects configuration in `glmer` is something like this...`(0+x1|ecoregion) + (1 | Ecoregion)`. Any odea on how you would rep[resent this within 'predict'..taking into account that the levels within 'ecoregion' are factors

Comment: you're right that I should have said `~1|ecoregion`.  If you use `re.form=NULL` (its default setting) you condition on all of the random effects.  (If you have a more detailed question than that you might want to post a new question ...)

Comment: `re.form=NULL` would work, like explained above in this particular case, I want to use only one of the two random effects..both are constructed as explained above....in this case  I want to use the 'ecoregion' random effect and not 'year'..

Comment: this seems to be trickling on somewhat. Assuming that you don't really have two different variables `ecoregion` and `Ecoregion`, you should just need `re.form=~(0+x1|ecoregion)+(1|ecoregion)` (or `re.form=~(1+x1||ecoregion)`, which should be equivalent`).  If that doesn't do it, please ask another question.